# showing and hiding divs by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four divs, the first is showing on load of the site. I am currently hiding the other three on load with CSS (display: none)

Within that first div that is showing, I have a button that on click, I want to hide the current div and then show the next div.

```
<div id="one">
            <h3>Placeholder</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form>    

</div><!--Closes One-->

<div id="two">
            <h3>Placeholder</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next2" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Two-->

<div id="three">
            <h3>Placeholder</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next3" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Three-->

<div id="four">
            <h3>Placeholder</h3>
</div><!--Closes Four-->
```

So im looking to create some Jquery to make this happen.

Here's the janky code I have that doesnt really work at all...

```
$("#next1").click(function(){
    $("#two").show();
    $("#one").hide();
});

$("#next2").click(function(){
    $("#three").show();
    $("#two").hide();
});

$("#next3").click(function(){
    $("#four").show();
    $("#three").hide();
});
```

Forgot CSS, my apologies!

```
#two, #three, #four {
  display: none;
  }
```

I assume I dont need to explicitly say to hide all three divs every time due to CSS already hiding two through four, and then altering one at a time through Jquery.

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: css is missing in action

Comment: Are you hiding the other three divs on load using jQuery or is the CSS style for the divs by default `display:none` ?

Comment: You are showing too that's why you need to hide the last `.show();` div;

Comment: Sorry, 

#two, #three, #four {
  display: none;
  }

For the css, and hiding them on load with CSS. From there showing and hiding with Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

(you used classes instead of ids for your elements)

```js
$("#next1").click(function(){
    $("#two").show();
    $("#one").hide();
});

$("#next2").click(function(){
    $("#three").show();
    $("#two").hide();
});

$("#next3").click(function(){
    $("#four").show();
    $("#three").hide();
});
```

```css
#two, #three, #four {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
            <h3>Placeholder 1</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form>    

</div><!--Closes One-->

<div id="two">
            <h3>Placeholder 2</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next2" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Two-->

<div id="three">
            <h3>Placeholder 3</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next3" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Three-->

<div id="four">
            <h3>Placeholder 4</h3>
</div><!--Closes Four-->
```

Comment: I noticed that, but edited it within like a minute of posting. You are fast and posted before the edit, thank you for the speedy response!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So this is the simple query which you are looking after

```
$(".btn-default").click(function(){
$(this).closest('div').hide();  //Gets the closest div associated with your button click
$(this).closest('div').next('div').show();   //hide the next div
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$("button.btn-default").click(function(){
$(this).closest('div').hide();  
$(this).closest('div').next('div').show();
});
```

```css
#two, #three, #four {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
            <h3>Placeholder 1</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form>    

</div><!--Closes One-->

<div id="two">
            <h3>Placeholder 2</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next2" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Two-->

<div id="three">
            <h3>Placeholder 3</h3>
            <form>
                    <button id="next3" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Next</button>
            </form> 
</div><!--Closes Three-->

<div id="four">
            <h3>Placeholder 4</h3>
</div><!--Closes Four-->
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to give each div it's own class or ID.

You could give them all the same class and use the jQuery eq: filter to choose the correct div.

Example code:

```
$(".custom button").click(function(){
    var nextDiv = $(this).attr('data-id'); // Usually a +1 for the next div, but since eq filter is zero based, it works in this case.

    $('.custom').hide();
    $('.custom:eq(' + nextDiv + ')').show();
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ore5h6tk/

Another example, hiding all but the first with CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/ore5h6tk/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if i have other divs after this that I dont want effected by the showing/hiding, will this effect that?

Comment: As long as you dont give them the same class, they will not be affected by the function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your code .Just make the four divs looks difference.

Comment: Hrmm, maybe my browser is acting up. It wont work. Even copy pasted the other guys code into a brand new document and its not working. Weird...

Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Fixed the issue. I didn't have the jquery within a document.ready function so it was trying to run before the buttons were even created. Works now, thanks!